# Simple Q about UIPickerView properties

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uilabel, uipickerview

Ok this is probably so simple that it's laughable, but I can't figure the answer. What is the property of the uipickerview? For the UIDatePicker, its datePicker.date, for label you can do label.text, etc etc. Is there a pickerView.XX syntax where I can get the value selected similar to the datePicker? Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[selectedRowInComponent:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW7)

You probably missed it b/c it isn't a property.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thanks